# Unity Mapbox Android Build Failure Manifest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I imported the Mapbox SDK (1.4.2) to my Unity project and wanted to build the project for Android. I want the app to run on the lowest Android version supported by Mapbox. According to the [Mapbox website](https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/#create-an-android-studio-project), the minimum API version is API 14 (Android 4.0.0). But when I try to build the project, it tells me that the library needs minimum API 24 (Android 7.0.0). However, I have set the project to have the minimum API 16 (Android 4.1) and the target API the highest installed (Android 8.1), so the project runs on every Android version in this range.

But when I try to build the project as .apk an error occurs indicating that the manifest merger failed.

[Image showing the error which occurs in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4MXH.png)

The two Android manifest .xml files are as followed:

```
/Users/user/Desktop/Project/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.mapbox.android.unity-debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

[(Image) Link to the content of the AndroidManifest.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuAoR.png)

```
/Users/user/Desktop/Project/Temp/StagingArea/AndroidManifest-main.xml
```

[(Image) Link to the content of the AndroidManifest-main.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u758u.png)

I don't know what to do. In the AndroidManifest.xml file it says that the minimum API version is 24 although I set the minimum API version in Unity to API 16 ([Another image showing that I set the minimum API version to 16 in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOobO.jpg)). I've als tried to change the minimum API version in the AndroidManifest.xml file but after every build it's API 24 again.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Seems my response was deleted because it wasn't an answer, but since then my colleague has gotten in touch with the Mapbox devs, and they've responded [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/831). Apparently, the Android Native GPS Plugin is set to support as low as level 24, which I don't understand given that the site claims the plugin supports much lower, unless I'm misreading it.

However, we implemented the fix in which you uncheck Android on the asset at

```
Assets/Mapbox/Unity/Location/Plugins/Android/com.mapbox.android.unity-debug
```

This seems to have worked.